# Clonezilla: Server No disk image found in /home/partimag.. make sure you already saved an image

Tags: ubuntu, cloning, clonezilla

I am trying to setup a cloning sever to restore disk images onto quite a few computers. When I am going through the dcs command I choose to restore a disk and in the terminal I get the error "No disk image found in /home/partimag."

I have tried storing the image file in /home/partimag. I have tried mounting the image to /home/partimag, to no avail.

Comment: Did you create the image file with clonezilla?

Comment: No I created the image file using dd.

Comment: Clonezilla will only recognize a clonezilla image. Create the image using clonezilla and you can restore that.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out that. For some reason it never crossed my mind. I also don think that is spelled out anywhere either for some reason.

Comment: Well, clonezilla's "What's Clonezilla" section of their main page says `Clonezilla is a partition and disk imaging/cloning program` and `Clonezilla live is suitable for single machine backup and restore` and `Clonezilla saves and restores only used blocks in the hard disk`. I think it makes it pretty clear it's also used to backup the data it restores.

Comment: True. But I tried using different iso/disk images for clonezilla server and could never find it. As soon as I used clonezilla live to create the image it found it. Anyway, thank you for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Clonezilla can only restore the images that it creates.

Try creating the image you want to restore using Clonezilla and try again.